# How to get css or java class for specific part of code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my code:

```html
<div id="togglemenu2" class="sidetogglemenu">
    <table class="hoverTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">  Example    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <img class="gpablogo" src="http://s2.postimg.org/yb2yzb5fd/gpab.png">
                    <div class="gpab1">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gpab2">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gpab3">
                        <p>3</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I move numbers 1,2,3 between G and P and Ab?  I need a CSS code to move those numbers look like this:

**G1   P2   AB3**

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to need javascript to move values between html elements.

Comment: So how to do it? Could you please give me a code to move them between elements? Thank you so much

Comment: If you want to insert your numbers (1 / 2 / 3) in between letters of your logo, you'll have to use absolute position, but this is not a good solution. Why don't you slice your logo into 3 parts (the G, the P, the Ab), and insert your numbers between? Or you could even use your logo as a background image!

Comment: Cause actually this logo is part of medical code and numbers should show something different. it's something specific in medical issue. If I slice it, then it's hard to sort them beside each other in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of realizing your layout.  Create a wrapping element `.logowrap` around the image and the labels, and specify `position: relative`.

You can then use absolute positioning to place the labels where you need them.

```css
.logowrap {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
}
.logowrap img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.logowrap .gpab {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 2.00em;
}
.gpab.n1 {
  left: 25%;
}
.gpab.n2 {
  left: 50%;
}
.gpab.n3 {
  left: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="togglemenu2" class="sidetogglemenu">
  <table class="hoverTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="logowrap">
          <img class="gpablogo" src="http://s2.postimg.org/yb2yzb5fd/gpab.png">
          <div class="gpab n1">1</div>
          <div class="gpab n2">2</div>
          <div class="gpab n3">3</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```